# PANDAS: Convert 2 row df to single row multilevel column df

Tags: python, pandas

I have been searching for an answer to my question for a while, and have not been able to find anything that produces my desired result.

The problem is this: I have a dataframe with two rows that I want to merge into a single row dataframe that has multi-level columns. Using my example below (which I drafted in excel to better visualize my desired output), I want the new DF to have a multicolumn index with the first level being based on the original columns A-C, then add a new column sub level based on the values from the original 'Name' column. It is quite possible i'm incorrectly using existing functions. If you could provide me with your simplest way of altering the dataframe, I would greatly appreciate it!

Code to construct current df:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['Alex',1,2,3],['Bob',4,5,6]],columns='Name A B 
C'.split())
```

Image of current df with desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `set_index` + `unstack`

```
df.set_index('Name').unstack().to_frame().T
Out[198]: 
        A        B        C    
Name Alex Bob Alex Bob Alex Bob
0       1   4    2   5    3   6
```